How do you diagram polysyndeton?
Polysyndeton is when you have multiple (extra) conjunctions in a list. Is there a convention for diagraming it in a sentence?
Here's a simple example:

He bought apples and bananas and grapes.

Of course, we could treat it like a normal list by dropping the first "and". But since omitting a word seems undesirable, my first thought was to write the conjunction twice:

I'm not sure whether this works in every case, but it's still possible even if there are only some extra conjunctions:

Hand me the hammer, and a nail, the screwdriver, and a screw.

(Note the lack of an "and" before "the screwdriver.")
Using the above form, you'd simply omit an "and" between "nail" and "screwdriver".
However, is this the right approach? Or at least, is this a common solution to the problem? I can't find any examples of polysyndeton with diagrams online.

For what it's worth, I (also) find these sentences a bit awkward. I'm trying to simplify constructions I've seen in literature. For an example, see the second sentence in Emily Wilson's translation of The Odyssey.

and-ing is already quite simple as grammatical / rhetorical structuring in concerned. I think that second sentence in Wilson's translation is quite good.

That form of diagramming is no longer being used. Now the diagrams look like a Calder mobile. https://calder.org/works/hanging-mobile/untitled-1936/

I vote to close this question because what really is a good way to parse bad grammar?
